# Android error while receiving data from server

Tags: java, android

I'm using code from [Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically) .

Im trying to receive data from server, to updatate my app.

After I click **Button** app crashes.

If you know hot to fix these errors tell me.

I get this errors:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

at com.example.appupdate.SelfInstall01Activity.GetVersionFromServer(SelfInstall01Activity.java:285)

at com.example.appupdate.SelfInstall01Activity$1.onClick(SelfInstall01Activity.java:89)
```

Ive got errors there:

```
btnCheckUpdates.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            GetVersionFromServer(BuildVersionPath);
           //here

            if(checkInstalledApp(AppName.toString()) == true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application Found " + AppName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application Not Found. "+ AppName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And:

```
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setDoOutput(true);
    c.connect();
    //here
```

Here is rest of code:

```
public void GetVersionFromServer(String BuildVersionPath)
{
URL u;
    try {
        u = new URL(BuildVersionPath.toString());

        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 


        int len1 = 0;
        while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) != -1 )
        {
            baos.write(buffer,0, len1); 
        }

        String temp = "";
        String s = baos.toString();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            i = s.indexOf("=") + 1;
            while (s.charAt(i) == ' ')
            {
                i++; 
            }
            while (s.charAt(i) != ';'&& (s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9' || s.charAt(i) == '.'))
            {
                temp = temp.toString().concat(Character.toString(s.charAt(i))) ;
                i++;
            }
            //
            s = s.substring(i); 
            temp = temp + " "; 
        }
        String[] fields = temp.split(" ");

        VersionCode = Integer.parseInt(fields[0].toString());
        VersionName = fields[1].toString();

        baos.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetworkOnMainThreadException occurs when you perform network operation in main thread.. you need to perform your network operation in doInBackground method

here your button click function should be like this.

```
btnCheckUpdates.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        { 
           new YourTask().execute();
        }
    });
```

And here is your Your network operation.

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, String,String> {
     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

         // put here your network operation method
           GetVersionFromServer(BuildVersionPath)

        return null;
     }

 }
```

Comment: I did it but i have errors in: // put here your network operation method
            GetVersionFromServer(String BuildVersionPath) and in button: new GetVersionFromServer(BuildVersionPath).execute();

Comment: you need to put `new YourTask().execute();` in your button click..check my updated code..

Answer (score 0):

NetworkOnMainThreadException will be thrown when you make network request in UI/Main thread. So you need to call GetVersionFromServer() off the main thread. 
Use Threads or AsyncTask.